# AWS boto3 resource proxies with SageMaker services

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I need to use a boto3 IAM connection with a proxy for SageMaker services run inside a VPC. Using the estimator class as just one example of a service I need to use (https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html) I am unsure exactly how to get this service to use a proxy for IAM when I call the fit() method. I am already passing in a configured SageMaker Session (https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/session.html#sagemaker.session.Session) and I believe it has something to do with this but I only see an option to pass in a boto3 session but I can't see any info on how to preconfigure an IAM resource to use a proxy.

Can anyone help?